# regex on phone number

Tags: php, regex, format, phone-number

Id like to capture user data which has the format

```
name phone address
```

I'm using the phone as the hook to identify the part before phone as name and part after it as address, the phone should have 6-12 digits and can have these characters as well "+()[]-. ". I tried this regex

```
(.*)\s([0-9]{6-12}[\+\s\(\)-\[\]\.]+)\s(.*)
```

But its not acknowledging the range part {6-12}. What am I doing wrong and is there a better regex approach ?

Comment: As has been said many times before, regex is not the right tool for every job.  I would recommend using PHP code to validate the phone number.

Comment: I don't think  `097667878[]+` it is valid phone no for any country, but the regex matches it after correction. If you will give some  test strings then it will be probably  easier for us to guide you.

Comment: The number can be entered flexibly it could be +61-2323-232-323 or just 2323231, the limiting factor is that it will be between 6-12 digits and can have hypens or spaces in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for the braces is `{6,12}` not `{6-12}`.